# How do I make this UPDATE only work within this while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on this for a couple days, and my brain has finally gone numb.  My UPDATE is just updating every StartDate in the database, but I want it to only act on the event that is in the while loop this UPDATE is contained in.  I think the code is probably fairly obvious, so here it is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ParentEventID='$tempParentEventID' AND GoogleID IS NULL";
$result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

                $tempDaysFromEvent = $row['DaysFromEvent'];
                $tempStartDate = $row['StartDate'];

                //IF STARTDATE IS DIFFERENT FROM HOW IT USED TO BE, UPDATE IT.
                list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $tempStartDate);
                $tempStartDate      =   $tempEndDate    =    date("Y-m-d", mktime (0,0,0,$month,$day+$tempDaysFromEvent,$year));


                mysql_query("UPDATE".$eventDatabase." SET
                StartDate = '$tempStartDate'");


            }
```

I hope the above is clear enough.  I am trying to change the StartDate in each $row as it goes through the loop.

Comment: what is the condition when the update has to take place?

Comment: You can set the `WHERE` condition in the `UPDATE` query to update only the required rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about adding a where clause.

```
"UPDATE table SET field = '$sValue' WHERE eventID = ".$aRow['eventId']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The query should be

```
 "UPDATE".$eventDatabase." SET  StartDate = '$tempStartDate' WHERE EventId =". $row['evenID'];
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add a `WHERE`-clause to your update-statement:

```
UPDATE table SET StartDate = ... WHERE [whatever*]
```

*you havn't posted you table definitions, but it sounds like you should use your event-id here.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `WHERE`-clause in your UPDATE-Statement to identify the row to be updated.